# How to best display in Terminal a MySQL SELECT returning too many fields?

Tags: mysql, command-line, select, putty

I'm using [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/) to run:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

`sometable` has many fields and this results in many columns trying to be displayed in the terminal. The fields wrap onto the next line so it is very hard to line up column titles with field values.

**What solutions are there for viewing such data in terminal?**

I don't have nor want access to phpMyAdmin - or any other GUI interfaces. I'm looking for command-line solutions such as this one: [Save MySQL Query results into text or CVS file](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)

Comment: The solution is for the developer to fix the bug that stops the terminal being expanded to wider than a single screen.

Comment: @Owl, is this really a bug? Do the solutions provided here not solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 779, accepted):

Terminate the query with `\G` ***in place of*** `;`.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable\G
```

This query displays the rows vertically, like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 Host: localhost
                   Db: mydatabase1
                 User: myuser1
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          ...
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                 Host: localhost
                   Db: mydatabase2
                 User: myuser2
          Select_priv: Y
          Insert_priv: Y
          Update_priv: Y
          ...
```

Comment: Despite the Windows being not case-sensitive, this `G` must be capitalized.

Comment: Just to clarify the above comment, when you type `SELECT * FROM sometable\G` you are sending the string to the mysql command line client, not Windows, which is why the `G` is case sensitive

Comment: Except it doesn't work that well with large quantities of records.

Comment: The linked documentation says:
"ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.Be careful about defining a delimiter that might occur within other words. For example, if you define the delimiter as X, you will be unable to use the word INDEX in statements."

Comment: I encountered this. Could you please tell me how to fix it? `sh: 1: less: not found
44 rows in set (0.01 sec)`

Comment: Your default pager program is set to `less` but you don't have it installed. Install it or change the pager.

Comment: I'm getting below error. (Note - using Postgresql. Can someone suggest the equivalent of how same to be done in Postgresql)
select * from my_table \G
invalid command \G
Try \? for help.

Comment: @AkashVerma For psql, you can apparently use \x _before_ the sql command to set output to key-value pairs instead of tabulated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26040852

Answer (score 413):

You might also find this useful (non-Windows only):

```
mysql> pager less -SFX
mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

This will pipe the output through the `less` command line tool which - with these parameters - will give you a tabular output that can be scrolled horizontally and vertically with the cursor keys.

Leave this view by hitting the `q` key, which will quit the `less` tool.

Comment: This and other potentially useful things are in my book. See my blog for a link, I don't want to put up amazon links here.

Comment: can be reset using nopager.

Comment: Searching in less is done by hitting `/` and then write the search string, which can also be regexes, and then press enter. Search forward by pressing `n` and backwards by pressing `N` (`Shift + n`).

Comment: `less` can do even more cool things. Using `&` you can filter (only show matching lines) the result further using regular expressions. This works in addition to the `/` search (which will still cause the highlighting). Reset the filter by hitting `&` again and then just pressing Return.

Comment: awesome! Just `pager less -S` works though. What do the `FX` options buy you?

Comment: F will quit less immediately, if the output already fits the screen. X is to prevent less from trying to clear the screen on exit. See the less man page.

Comment: I did this for mysql but it is reflecting my rails pry console. I did reset using nopager but my rails pry console still formats output using less. How can I reset it?

Comment: this is switch on usual linux behaviour for long lists - use navigation keys and 'q' for quit. Nice variant! But, how store this setting as default for my console?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611974/how-do-you-set-a-default-pager-for-the-mysql-client on how to set a default pager for a MySQL client on the command line or config file.

Comment: To set it persistently, add `pager = less -SFX` to your `my.conf`

Comment: where is the my.conf file?

Comment: @Jwan622 AFAIK it is `my.cnf` -- without the `o`

Comment: @DanielSchneller The `less` manpage is so hard to understand compared to your explanation. I read `SFX` but only see `X` matches your comment. I mean, I can't not deduce the same meaning as yours after I read the manpage..

Answer (score 61):

### Using `mysql`'s `ego` command

From `mysql`'s `help` command:

> ego          (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.

So by appending a `\G` to your `select`, you can get a very clean vertical output:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable \G
```

### Using a pager

You can tell MySQL to use the `less` pager with its `-S` option that chops wide lines and gives you an output that you can scroll with the arrow keys:

```
mysql> pager less -S
```

Thus, next time you run a command with a wide output, MySQL will let you browse the output with the `less` pager:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable;
```

If you're done with the pager and want to go back to the regular output on `stdout`, use this:

```
mysql> nopager
```

Comment: This! Beautiful, only way to make this more perfect is to have a way to see how far the columns stretch horizontally. Like a scrollbar. Nevertheless, great solution.

Answer (score 52):

Try enabling vertical mode, using `\G` to execute the query instead of `;`:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sometable \G
```

Your results will be listed in the vertical mode, so each column value will be printed on a separate line.  The output will be narrower but obviously much longer.

Comment: as a complement to `\G`, you can also use `\g`as a replacement for `;`, I know, who would do that, but it gives context to why `\G`workd in the first place.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the `--table` or `-t` option, which will output a nice looking set of results

```sh
echo 'desc table_name' | mysql -uroot database -t
```

or some other method to pass a query to mysql, like:

```sh
mysql -uroot table_name --table < /tmp/somequery.sql
```

output:

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username     | varchar(30)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| first_name   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(75)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password     | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_staff     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_superuser | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 12):

Just to complement the answer that I thought best, I also use `less -SFX` but in a different way: I like to ad it to my `.my.cnf` file in my home folder, an example cnf file looks like this:

```
[client]
user=root
password=MyPwD
[mysql]
pager='less -SFX'
```

The good thing about having it this way, is that `less` is only used when the output of a query is actually more than one page long, here is the explanation of all the flags:

- -S: Single line, don't skip line when line is wider than screen, instead allow to scroll to the right.
- -F: **Quit if one screen**, if content doesn't need scrolling then just send to stdout.
- -X: No init, disables any output "less" might have configured to output every time it loads.

Note: in the `.my.cnf` file don't put the `pager` command below the `[client]` keyword; although it might work with `mysql` well, `mysqldump` will complain about not recognizing it.

Comment: Note that if you execute a "limit-less" query on a large table, you will not notice the chaos caused by it because `less` will stay anchored to the first line of the output.

Answer (score 11):

The default pager is stdout. The stdout has the column limitation, so the output would be wrapped. You could set other tools as pager to format the output. There are two methods. One is to limit the column, the other is to processed it in vim.

The first method:

```
➜  ~  echo $COLUMNS
179

mysql> nopager
PAGER set to stdout
mysql> pager cut -c -179
PAGER set to 'cut -c -179'
mysql> select * from db;
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-
| Host      | Db         | User       | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-
| %         | test       |            | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | N          | Y               | Y          | Y          |
| %         | test\_%    |            | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | N          | Y               | Y          | Y          |
| localhost | phpmyadmin | phpmyadmin | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | N          | Y               | Y          | Y          |
| localhost | it         | it         | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | N          | Y               | Y          | Y          |
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+-
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The output is not complete. The content fits to your screen.

The second one:

Set vim mode to nowrap in your .vimrc

```
➜  ~  tail ~/.vimrc

" no-wrap for myslq cli
set nowrap

mysql> pager vim -
PAGER set to 'vim -'
mysql> select * from db;
    Vim: Reading from stdin...
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------
| Host      | Db         | User       | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_pr
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------
| %         | test       |            | Y           | Y           | Y
| %         | test\_%    |            | Y           | Y           | Y
| localhost | phpmyadmin | phpmyadmin | Y           | Y           | Y
| localhost | it         | it         | Y           | Y           | Y
+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+----------
~
~
~
```

Comment: This worked best for me in a lightweight docker container. `pager cut -c -200`. The more accepted answers here required me to download unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL interactively, you can set your pager to use `sed` like this:

```
$ mysql -u <user> p<password>
mysql> pager sed 's/,/\n/g' 
PAGER set to 'sed 's/,/\n/g''
mysql> SELECT blah FROM blah WHERE blah = blah 
.
.
.
"blah":"blah"
"blah":"blah"
"blah":"blah"
```

If you don't use `sed` as the pager, the output is like this:

```
"blah":"blah","blah":"blah","blah":"blah"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `pspg` - https://github.com/okbob/pspg

This pager is designed for tabular data - and MySQL is supported too.

```
MariaDB [sakila]> pager pspg -s 14 -X --force-uniborder --quit-if-one-screen
PAGER set to 'pspg -s 14 -X --force-uniborder --quit-if-one-screen'
MariaDB [sakila]> select now();
MariaDB [sakila]> select * from nicer_but_slower_film_list limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe putty has a maximum number of columns you can specify for the window.

For Windows I personally use Windows PowerShell and set the screen buffer width reasonably high. The column width remains fixed and you can use a horizontal scroll bar to see the data. I had the same problem you're having now.

edit: For remote hosts that you have to SSH into you would use something like plink + Windows PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tee` to write the result of your query to a file:

```
tee somepath\filename.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

Using the Windows Command Prompt you can increase the buffer size of the window as much you want to see the number of columns. This depends on the no of columns in the table.