# How do you set a default pager for the MySQL client?

Tags: mysql

I know you can set a pager in `mysql` (the client program) using e.g. `\P less`. But how would one configure `mysql` so that your pager of choice is activated whenever you start using the client?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To force this without having to pass parameters, you can put it in your [`my.cnf` option file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html), under a `[client]` section (note that this is on the machine you're connecting *from* not *to*).

Something like this:

```
[client]
user = my_usual_user
host = my_usual_host
pager = less
```

If you want it to apply *only* to the actual `mysql` command, and no other applications that MySQL considers to be a 'client' (utilities like `mysqldump` read the `[client]` section too), then use `[mysql]` instead.

Comment: doesnt work with mariadb 11.3.2

Answer (score 8):

You can either start mysql with `--pager[=command]` commandline option or set custom pager via `PAGER` environment variable (which is used by default).

Comment: The flag works, but the PAGER environment variable doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

Comment: @dan: Heh.. might be a bug then :)

Comment: I don't think that's a bug, the PAGER env var is only used when you specify `--pager` without a command. "If you specify no value for the option, mysql checks the value of the PAGER environment variable and sets the pager to that."

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 5.5, you can add the `pager` when you open the mysql client. Use:

```
mysql  -h * --port=* --pager="less -SFX" databaseName
```

You can get more info about the `pager` options by using:

```
man mysql
```

or

```
man less
```