# disable automatic line wrapping in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I used some sql command to join two tables and the result was two terminal line long for each row of resulted table.

I dont want so ... i mean is there any way to get scroll bar at the bottom so that a row can be fit into a terminal line. and it will be a well structured and readable output

I hope you get my question.

Comment: Increase the width of your terminal window!

Comment: @devnull what do you mean by increase the width ... it's already full screen (maximize and F11 also) but still few columns of a row wraped into new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way on a standard terminal. You could use e.g. `less` as your pager for you sql-client.

Comment: you mean something like  
**SELECT * FROM table_name less**

Comment: No. when connecting to your databaseserver like e.g. via mysql or psql the output of your query is shown inside the pager --- at least most likely. For MySQL e.g. there is an answer available e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611974/how-do-you-set-a-default-pager-for-the-mysql-client

Answer (score 1):

I propose to pipe the output into the command `less -S`:

```
$ mysql-command-doing-the-SELECT | less -S
```

(To achieve this in the interactive `mysql` console, you can type `pager less -S`.)

Then all lines are *displayed* without being wrapped, and you can scroll sideways using the arrow keys.  You can also use the command `less` (without the option `-S`) and then interactively type <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to achieve the non-wrapping.  (Type again to toggle.)

If you need a real scroll bar, I propose to pipe the output into a real file and then use a more sophisticated program like `gedit` (which can be switched to a non-wrapping display) to display it with a decent scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: copy the data from the terminal and paste it into your favorite editor. The copied text will not have any line breaks "\n".

(Offtopic: on a linux system you can just select the text with a mouse and mouse-middle-click in your editor. This will copy the text without filling out the main copy-paste buffer.)